# How to check the headers between 2 CSV files in unix?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ksh

```
File1 - filename.csv
File2 - filename.csv
```

I wanted to compare the headers between these 2 files in linux using a ksh script.

case 1:-

Say,
the header of file1 is INPUT -->

```
NAME,UNIT CODE, VAR
JAMES01,IPU UNIT,OTHER
FIERCY,AUTOIMMUNE,OTHER
```

the header of file2 is INPUT -->

OUTPUT:- there is a match in header between these 2 files

case 2:-

Say,
the header of file1 is INPUT --> plant,animal,object
the header of file2 is INPUT --> plant,animal,object,tree

OUTPUT - there's a excess column, EXCESS COLUMN NAME IS 'tree'

FYI- please see that the header is getting fetched from the csv file and not hardcoded.
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Can you convert the xlsx file to a simpler format? For instance, open it and then save as `.csv` or tab separated? If so, please [edit] your question and show us a few lines of the two files (use the `{}` button to mark them as code) and then also show us the output you would expect from that example input. Finally, are you really using UNIX or did you mean Linux? And are you using bash or ksh?

Comment: Thanks @terdon using a ksh script and on linux. edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, but please answer the first question about excel: do you absolutely _have_ to use xlsx files or can you use a regular, simple text format like tsv or csv? Can you convert the files? And then, we need to see actual examples of the input data and required output we can't help otherwise.

Comment: No, i have converted the files to csv for both the files. Actual samples has been updated and code highlighted using the {} button

Comment: You need to select the text you want to show as code and _then_ click on the `{}` button. Please make sure both input and output is formatted as code so we know what you need. And make sure you show us the _actual_ contents of the file. You mention "csv" but you show space-separated fields. What is the field separator?

Comment: please show us your data. Remove all this "INPUT" and "OUTPUT" just add the actual data. Then, select the lines and mark them as code with `{}`. I _think_ you have comma separated fields, but it is helpful if we can see an actual example.

Comment: May I don't understand the question... It's help? `diff <(head -n 1 cvfile1|tr ',' '\n') <(head -n 1 cvfile2|tr ',' '\n') |grep '^[<>]'`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is just compare the first lines of each file and move to the right directory depending on if they are identical:

```
$ diff -qs <(head -n1 file1.csv) <(head -n1 file2.csv) 
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ
```

You can then use the `&&` (and) and `||` (or) operators to do different things to the file depending on the result. For instance, if `file2.csv` has the same header, move it to a directory called `same` and if it is different, move to a directory named `different`:

```
$ mkdir -p same different
$ diff -qs <(head -n1 file1.csv) <(head -n1 file2.csv) && 
   mv file2.csv same/ || mv file2.cxv different/
```

If you really need to know the specific field that is different, and can be sure the difference will always be the last field, you can do:

```
diff -qs <(head -n1 file1.csv) <(head -n1 file2.csv) >/dev/null && 
   echo "The headers are the same" ||
   echo "file2.csv has an extra entry: $(awk -F, '{ print $NF; exit}' file2.csv)"
```

If the you need to handle *any* difference, use:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
       { 
        if(NR==FNR){ 
          for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ a[$i]++ }
        }
        else{ 
         for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ 
          if (! ($i in a)){
            b[$i]++
          }
         }
        }
       }
       END{ 
            printf "The second file has extra fields: ";
            for( field in b){
                printf "\"%s\" ", field
           }
       }' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do, untested and using an awk that supports `nextfile`, e.g. GNU awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS="," }
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
        nf = split($0,a)
        nextfile
    }
    FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
        nf = (NF > nf ? NF : nf)
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            if ( $i"" != a[i]"" ) {
                printf "Field %d difference: %s \"%s\" != %s \"%s\"\n", i, ARGV[1], a[i], FILENAME, $i
            }
        }
        exit
    }
' file1.csv file2.csv
```

if your awk doesn't support `nextfile` then change this:

```
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
        nf = split($0,a)
        nextfile
    }
```

to this:

```
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
        if ( NR == 1 ) {
            nf = split($0,a)
        }
        next
    }
```

and it'll still work, just run a but slower as it'll have to read the whole first file instead of just the first line of it.

The above assumes the 2nd file is not empty. If it could be then populate a second array in the `FILENAME == ARGV[2]` spot and then compare them in the `END` section.